# Update column based on another column in table - MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table, titled Game, structured like this:

```
[Game_Name]      [Publisher]
```

The data in the table would look like this:

```
[Game_Name]      [Publisher]
                     1
                     3
                     1
                     2
                     2
                     1
                     3
```

And Game_Name will be blank. With this, I want to update the value of Game_Name based on the value of the Publisher column.

How this should work:

If the Publisher = 1 -> for each of the instances (rows) where the Publisher column is 1, the Game_Name will be GM-1,...GM-n. So, in this example, there are 3 instances where Publisher is 1. So the values would be GM-1, GM-2, GM-3.

If the publisher = 2, similar to the above, expect the format is 1-1,...n-n. So, since we have 2 instances where Publisher is 2, the values for Game_Name would be GM-1-1, GM-2-2.

Lastly, if Publisher = 3, the values for Game_Name would be 1-1-1,...n-n-n. There are three instances here so the values for Game_Name would be GM-1-1-1, GM-2-2-2, GM-3-3-3.

This is my current approach

```
UPDATE Game
SET Game_Name = 
SWITCH (Publisher = 1, "GM-"&[1+1],
Publisher = 2, "GM-"&[1+1]&"-"&[1+1],
Publisher = 3, "GM-"&[1+1]&"-"&[1+1]&"-"&[1+1])
```

I am having trouble keeping track of the incrementing value and when to reset. Also, whether this should be a Macro or not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As records have _no order_ - unless specified, and that's not the case - use Excel for this.

Comment: Hm. Good point. Do you have any recommendations as to how I could structure this in Access to meet the goal?

Comment: Add an _AutoNumber_ field with sequential numbering.

Comment: Hm ok, but if I had, say 7 examples. Then I would have an ID column that goes 1-7. How could that help me?

Comment: You can sort on that. You could also use a date field with date/time for the game.

Comment: Would this be on a specific macro? What would I sort?

Comment: You will have to sort on something to obtain the sequence of Publisher, you have posted, which is non-sortable as is.

Comment: Alright, I sorted the column so it is ordered by. Do you know how I should proceed?

Comment: Are there only 3 publisher values? This will quickly get unmanageable if there are more. Use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT ID, Publisher, "GM-" & Choose([Publisher],[GrpSeq],[GrpSeq] & "-" & [GrpSeq],[GrpSeq] & "-" & [GrpSeq] & "-" & [GrpSeq]) AS Game_Name
FROM (SELECT ID, Publisher, DCount("*","Game","Publisher = " & [Publisher] & " AND ID <" & [ID])+1 AS GrpSeq FROM Game) AS Q1;
```

Be aware this will likely perform slowly with very large dataset. In which case a VBA approach would probably be preferable. If there are significantly more than 3 Publisher values, VBA approach may be only option.

Comment: This is really impressive. Thanks. I just need to insert these values into the table.